# Why gravity doesn't center all of my views?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-gravity

I was expecting all my TextView to be vertically centered in my RelativeLayout but this is only the case for the logo one. The others are anchored to the top of the latter.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxhPu.png)

Here's my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stop"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/direction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `layout_toEndOf` performs layouting as follows:

> Positions the start edge of this view to the end of the given anchor view ID. [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Which means that all your `TextView`s start edges align with the `logo`'s end.
As a starting point, just remove all `layout_toEndOf` attributes.

Then your layout should look something like this:

```
+--------------+
|              | +-----------+
|              | |   stop    |
|              | +-----------+ +-----------+
|     logo     |/* no space */ |    eta    |
|              | +-----------+ +-----------+
|              | | direction |
|              | +-----------+
+--------------+
```

More precisely, `logo` is vertically centered, same as `eta`. Since your layout code explictly places `stop` and `direction` directly to the right of `logo`, therefore `direction` is below `stop`.